# How to forward a port in Azure?

Tags: azure, docker, port-forwarding

I installed a blogging software in azure which internaly run on Port 2368.
I exposed the port and it is working but of course I dont want my site visitors to write myblog.com:2368.

So as I googled allready a port mapping like AWS or Docker do is not possible in Azure right now.

What other solution could I have here?

I thought about getting a load balancer, or just a forwarder or reverse proxy here, but all that are just theories in my head because I never had something like that set up.

Comment: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/ ?

Comment: Might be, can you expand this with an example please?

Comment: That’s a link to a reverse proxy.

Comment: And you think that is what I need? How to work with that? Never setup a reverse proxy

Comment: Follow the [directions](https://ghost.org/docs/install/ubuntu/). Do not skip steps.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would probably be creating a loadbalancer that does the port forwarding for you. For more info/a tutorial see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/tutorial-load-balancer-port-forwarding-portal

Comment: That could actually work! Tahk you, I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do port forwarding in Azure. It's easier to be done on a classic VM, you just need to make a new endpoint. Check this link: [Open ports to Azure VM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal)

On newer type VMs, you need to use Azure Resourse Manager I think. I left Azure platform, so my experience is on classic VMs. An Azure load balancer is an option of course, as is a reverse proxy, although probably an overkill for your case.

Comment: I dont want to have a VM, i just want to use docker please

Comment: Can you clarify your setup? Sorry, I didn't understand.